# Athena query fails with boto3 (S3 location invalid)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

I'm trying to execute a query in Athena, but it fails.

Code:

```
client.start_query_execution(QueryString="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db;",
                           QueryExecutionContext={'Database': 'db'},
                           ResultConfiguration={
                                     'OutputLocation': "s3://my-bucket/",
                                     'EncryptionConfiguration': {
                                             'EncryptionOption': 'SSE-S3'
                                             }
                                     })
```

But it raises the following exception:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) 
when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: The S3 location provided to save your 
query results is invalid. Please check your S3 location is correct and is in the same 
region and try again. If you continue to see the issue, contact customer support 
for further assistance.
```

However, if I go to the Athena Console, go to Settings and enter the same S3 location (for example):

[image: athena settings]

the query runs fine.

What's wrong with my code? I've used the API of several the other services (eg, S3) successfully, but in this one I believe I'm passing some incorrect parameters.  Thanks.

Python: 3.6.1.  Boto3: 1.4.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**: As suggested by Justin, AWS later added support for Athena by adding `athena` prefix to the bucket. Please upvote his answer.

---

**Accepted Answer**:

The S3 location provided to save your query results is invalid. **Please check your S3 location is correct and is in the same region** and try again.

Since it works when you use the console, it is likely the bucket is in a different region than the one you are using in `Boto3`. Make sure you use the correct region (the one that worked in the console) when constructing the `Boto3` client. By default, `Boto3` will use the region configured in the credentials file.

Comment: Don't edit "Workgroup" s3 bucket, you actually want to click 'Settings" in Athena Query Editor (top right)

Answer (score 22):

I had to add a 'athena-' prefix to my bucket to get it to work.  For example, in stead of:

"s3://my-bucket/"

Try:

"s3://athena-my-bucket/"

Comment: This worked! WOW, I spent exactly 8 hours debugging this connection. Thanks.

Comment: I have to admit that I thought this solution was insane but it worked!

Comment: Don't edit "Workgroup" s3 bucket, you actually want to click 'Settings" in Athena Query Editor (top right)

Comment: Does anyone know why this works or have a link to AWS docs explaining this solution?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively try `boto3.client('athena', region_name = '<region>')`

Ran into the same issue and needed to specify the S3 bucket in the client.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, IAM role didn't have all the permissions for the S3 bucket. I gave IAM role following permissions for Athena results bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::athena_results_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::athena_results_bucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I see a couple of issues with that policy:
1: one S3 resource need a wilcard: `arn:aws:s3:::athena_results_bucket/*`
2: `"s3:GetBucketLocation"` might be needed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I received the OP error, attempted Justin's answer, and got the following error

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:15: Schema TableName does not exist
```

Meaning that it was not able to find the tables that I had previously created through the AWS Athena UI.

The simple solution was to use dclaze's answer instead. These two answers cannot be used simultaneously, or you will get back the initial (OP) error.