# Outputting Athena Query Result to s3 bucket in a different AWS Account from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I am trying to set up a lambda to run an AWS Athena query daily and output the result to an s3 bucket stored in a different AWS Account. The account I am writing the Lambda in has s3 write permissions in the other account, I just can't figure out how to input the specific bucket I'm looking to write to, and I haven't been able to find any documentation on this use case.

The following is how I'm running my athena query from the lambda:

```html
client = boto3.client('athena')
client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = [QUERY],
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': [DATABASE]
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': [OUTPUT_LOCATION]
        }
    )
```

My query works fine when storing the result in my own AWS account. I can't just write "s3://[BUCKETNAME]" where bucket name is the name of the bucket in the other account.

I'm guessing there is something very simple I'm missing--if anyone could tell me how to format "OUTPUT_LOCATION" where ACCOUNT_ID is the id of the other account and BUCKET_NAME is the name of the bucket, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Have you tried it with a slash after the bucket name? `s3://BUCKETNAME/` What error are you receiving?

Comment: Did you find answer ??

Comment: S3 Bucket and Athena database should be in same region. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313763/athena-query-fails-with-boto3-s3-location-invalid?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

> Bucket names must be unique within a partition. A partition is a grouping of Regions. AWS currently has three partitions: aws (Standard Regions), aws-cn (China Regions), and aws-us-gov (AWS GovCloud [US] Regions).

Refer this [doc on the naming standards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules)

When defining the name of an S3 bucket you do not have to specify an account ID.

For Example, an ARN for s3 bucket would be without the account ID

`arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>`

whereas an ARN for a resource or Role would have its Account ID

`arn:aws:iam::<MyAccountA>:role/<MyRoleA>`

```
client = boto3.client('athena')
client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = [QUERY],
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': [DATABASE]
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://<BUCKET_NAME>`' # Even when the bucket is another AWS account
        }
    )
```

If the query fails, start looking at permissions. Your code is right.

Comment: Nice first answer!